# How does trig work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I have a value and its cosine as:

```
-0.2567721374914637
Cosine: -0.04253775592822526
```

Compare what we get in Python:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.cos(-0.2567721374914637)
0.9672147629178562
```

Is there a way I can do trig in JavaScript that isn't out to lunch?

Are there any math libraries or anything that provide working trigonometry?

--EDIT--

The code where I was getting the results reported were:

```
            var distance_along = (high_noon.getTime() / 1000 -
              summer_solstice.getTime() / 1000)
              / (winter_solstice.getTime() / 1000
              - summer_solstice.getTime() / 1000);
            console.log(distance_along);
            console.log('Cosine: ' + Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * distance_along));
            var added_degrees = (Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * distance_along) * 
              ANCIENT_CLOCK.earth_tilt);
```

That reported, for a distance along of

```
-0.2567721374914637
Cosine: -0.04253775592822526
```

Regarding the question of looking things up: I did not do extensive looking up of how to handle a cosine. I knew that JavaScript had a Math library, and thought the logical place to look for it was in Math.cos(). However, it reported the values above.

Comment: Type this in your console : Math.cos(-0.2567721374914637)

Comment: How did you get that -0.04253775592822526 ? Since you just written `Cosine:` I'm interested in the actual function you used.

Comment: And I see the consensus is that I'm silly and did not mention basic research...

Comment: But if you go to <http://jonathanscorner.com/ancient-clock/>, in Mint Chrome, the logging statements report Math.cos(-0.2567721374914637) to be -0.04253775592822526

Comment: Umm, `console.log('Cosine: ' + Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * distance_along));` If you let Python compute `math.cos(2*π*(-0.2567721374914637))` (where `π` is a reasonably good approxiamtion to π), it will come back with approximately the same result. You computed something entirely different in Python.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this javascript like this:

```
//Return the cosine of a number:
Math.cos(3);
// -0.9899924966004454
```

You can get the full list of Math objects here: [JavaScript Math Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)

Comment: sry mate but -1 for referencing w3schools

Comment: @fmsf That seems a bit rude to me. He gave a correct answer (to a pretty silly question). I think it's only fair to _at least_ mention _why_ you don't like his answer and _suggest an alternative_ . This has been discussed _several_ times in Meta.

Comment: @fmsf I don't like w3schools either but in my opinion you shouldn't downvote just for that unless you find an error in this page.

Comment: ok I'll just edit his question and remove the downvote then

Comment: @fmsf Thanks. Appreciated http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: For the record, I will never post any _w3schools_ resource ever.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `Math` object:

```
Math.cos(-0.25)
0.9689124217106447
```

You can find all functions available in `Math` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

Comment: And in javascript: `Math.cos(-0.2567721374914637) == 0.9672147629178562` which is the same as the PHP answer.