# Why is my program making the computer appear to do bad trigonometry?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

In my code, I have:

```
console.log(distance_along);
console.log('Cosine: ' + Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * distance_along));
var added_degrees = 
  (ANCIENT_CLOCK.cos(2 * Math.PI * distance_along) * ANCIENT_CLOCK.earth_tilt);
```

This produces the output:

```
-0.2567721374914637
Cosine: -0.04253775592822526
```

With more code at http://JonathansCorner.com/ancient-clock

What have I done wrong, and how can I fix it? The first logged value is in radians (modulo the multiplier of 2π), the second logged value is the cosine of a completely different number. Why?

My earlier post gave the impression that I didn't know about `Math.cos()`. I do know about `Math.cos()` and don't know why it appears to be producing a value at variance for what other people have reported for `cos(-0.2567721374914637)` in JavaScript and PHP.

I am running Mint Chrome.

Comment: Did you expect `cos(-0.2567721374914637)` and `cos(2 * Math.PI * -0.2567721374914637)` to be the same value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does trig work in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387316/how-does-trig-work-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm confused too, javascripts `Math.cos(-1.6)` = `~-0.029` but my windows calculator says `cos(-1.6)` = `~1`

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko Windows calculator works in degrees and Javascript works in radians.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> console.log(distance_along); // -0.2567721374914637
> console.log(Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * distance_along)); // -0.04253775592822526
> ```
>
> What have I done wrong, and how can I fix it? The first logged value is in radians (modulo the multiplier of 2π), the second logged value is the cosine of a completely different number. Why?

Because you multiplied the number in radians with 2π, which is that completely different number. Yet, [`Math.cos`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos) *does* expect its argument to be in radians. Use

```
console.log(Math.cos(distance_along)); // 0.9672147629178562
```

Answer (score 2):

@jonathanhayward I think you have a conceptual problem with trig and/or trig functions.

I have read your question 5 times and think you want:

```
console.log(Math.cos(distance_along));
console.log('Cosine: ' + Math.cos(2 * Math.PI + distance_along));
```

OR

```
console.log(distance_along);
console.log('Cosine: ' + (Math.cos(2 * Math.PI) * distance_along));
```

FYI:

```
Math.cos(2 * Math.PI + distance_along) == Math.cos(distance_along) // is true
```